# An html table calendar using CSS positioned numbers

Tags: html, css, calendar, html-table

I would like to create a full-page calendar using html that behaves as you might think it would.  It does its best to display the whole month in one screen.  Any text that doesn't 
fit into the table cell causes a little scrollbar to appear for that day.

The code I have so far behaves itself pretty well in Chrome except that the day numbers tend to get squashed into the previous week.

[image: chrome rendering of the calendar]

In Firefox it ignores the overflow setting of the table cells, so the table cells lose their scrollbars.

[image: firefox rendering of the same calendar]

(not concerning myself with IE)

My question is:  How can I get the numbers to behave themselves.  If Firefox could render the same way too, that would be a bonus.

Here's the CSS:

```
/* for looking at the outlines of things */
 * {
    border:1px dashed #0000FF;
}
.scrollable_table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
}
.calendar_num {
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
    margin-top:1px;
}
.calendar_row {
    width:100%;
}
.calendar_td {
    width:14%;
    /*height:14%; */
}
.scrollable_td {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's some example code for a 'typical' month:

```
<html><head>
  <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/static/calendar.css' />
  <body>
    <table class=scrollable_table>
      <tr class=calendar_row>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>1</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 1
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=calendar_row>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>2</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 2
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>3</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 3
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>4</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 4
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>5</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 5
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>6</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 6
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>7</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 7
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>8</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 8
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class=calendar_row>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>9</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 9
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>10</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 10
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>11</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 11
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>12</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 12
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>13</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 13
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>14</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 14
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>15</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 15
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=calendar_row>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>16</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 16
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>17</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 17
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>18</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 18
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>19</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 19
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>20</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 20
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>21</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 21
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>22</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 22
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=calendar_row>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>23</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 23
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>24</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 24
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>25</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 25
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>26</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 26
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>27</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 27
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>28</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 28
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>29</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 29
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class=calendar_row>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>30</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 30
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td>
          <div class=calendar_num>31</div>
          <div class=scrollable_td>day: 31
            <br/>a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow off the end of the td. a bunch of text that could flow o
        </td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
        <td class=calendar_td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is a fiddle [calendar fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashdottir/xqJAC/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
/* for looking at the outlines of things */
 * {
    border:1px dashed #0000FF;
}
.scrollable_table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cell-spacing:0;
    cell-padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
}
.calendar_num {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:20px;
    text-align:right;
    width:100%;
}
.calendar_row {
    width:100%;
}
.calendar_td {
    width:14%;
    position:relative;
}
.scrollable_td {
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/xqJAC/11/)

Comment: This one also is toast in firefox

Comment: Just tried this again and it works in firefox  just fine.  I think it is the new answer.

Comment: While I do agree on the new answer. I want to point out that [there was a bug for nearly 18 years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168) that prevented the use of position absolute elements like intended within tables. This bug have been solved and therefore this is the correct answer as of today.

Answer (score 1):

The only fix i can come up with is replaceing the `<div>`s against `<textarea>`

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/xqJAC/15/

Version2: http://jsfiddle.net/xqJAC/19/

If you always use 6 rows, you can define a row height of 16.666%, then this is more clean:

```
 *
{ 
    border:1px dashed #0000FF; 
}


html,body
{
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; 
}

.scrollable_table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
}

.scrollable_table tbody  > tr
{ 
    height: 16.666%;
}

.calendar_num {
    text-align: right;
    height: 20px;
}

.scrollable_table td
{
   vertical-align: top;
   overflow: hidden;
}


.inline-area
{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that seems to be working in both browsers.  Like it.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but in version 1 the height is not always 100%. I posted a fix for that, that works if you always post 6 rows. Upated some more. The Td's need overflow:hidden; also.

Comment: Second version even better, thanks.  It would be ideal if it didn't have to be text areas, so there could be clickable links and stuff, but maybe this is the best that can be done with a table layout.

Comment: There is one error left. Chrome eats the overflow. I just fixed that

Comment: nice.  chrome and firefox nearly indistinguishable now.  It even works in IE - bonus!